# How to pass input type as array with comma seperated and read them in php

Tags: php, arrays, input

Hi friends am trying to pass the input type as array.

Here is my code..

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_tags'])){
$videoid=$_POST['tags_list'];
echo sizeof($videoid);
?>
}
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="tags_list[]">
<input type="submit" name="submit_tags">
</form>
```

But am unable to read them for example I want to pass hello,how,are,you,why
but am unable to read them after when I pass them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. You only need one texbox. No need for multiple textbox. Try this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit_tags'])){
    $tagsList=$_POST['tags_list'];
    $videoids = explode(",", $tagsList);
    echo sizeof($videoids);
    }
    ?>
```

Also you can remove the [] from your textbox name `name="tags_list[]"` to `name="tags_list"`

Answer (score 0):

Sravya try to understand the concept first, `name as an array` in a html element is used when you want to make more than one html element as same type so that you can get its value by iterating the array like:

```
<input type="text" name="tags_list[]"> -> its value is one
<input type="text" name="tags_list[]"> -> its value is two
<input type="text" name="tags_list[]"> -> its value is three
```

You can print its values like:

```
print_r($tags_list);
```

Otherwise use single html element.

Comment: Break it by space or something else

Answer (score 0):

1) To send a input value as array to PHP, you need to set one value per input

```
<input type="text" name="tags_list[]" value="hello">
<input type="text" name="tags_list[]" value="world">
```

Now the PHP can understand $_POST['tag_list'] as array.

2) You can change your approach and split the string.

```
<input type="text" name="tags_list" value="hello, world">
```

And transform the $_POST['tag_list'] string into an array. Example:

```
$tag_list = explode(', ', $_POST['tag_list']);
```

Or you can use preg_split function to add more intelligence to your string transformation.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

To read(convert string) from array you can use `implode`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_tags'])){
$videoid=$_POST['tags_list'];
echo implode(",",$videoid);
}
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="tags_list[]">
<input type="text" name="tags_list[]">
<input type="text" name="tags_list[]">
<input type="submit" name="submit_tags">
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah but the user in input enters like hello,how,are,why so how can I use ot to generate multiple inputs

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$variableAry=explode(",",$variable); //you have array now
            foreach($variableAry as $var)
            {
                echo $var. "<br/>";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_tags'])){

    $videoid=$_POST['tags_list'];
    $tag_list = explode(', ', $videoid);
    print_r($tag_list);

}
?>

    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="tags_list[]">
    <input type="text" name="tags_list[]">
    <input type="text" name="tags_list[]">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_tags">
    </form>
```